# scalate scalatra NoValueSetException with jade

Tags: pug, scalatra, scalate

I'm using Scalatra with Scalate and Jade. When ever I try to apply a template that takes values the values are not being applied to the template and I'm getting a NoValueSetException... Here is the code I have:

```
// --------- In PostsServlet ------------------
get("/:page") {
  /*
  val page:Int = params.getOrElse("page", "1").toInt
  val posts = PostCollection.page(page)
  */
  contentType="text/html"
  jade("/index.jade", "foo" -> "bar")
}


// ------------------ In index.jade ----------------------
-@ var foo : String

-attributes("title") = "Circuits Of Imagination"
-attributes("headline") = "Writings"
```

and the exception:

```
The value for 'foo' was not set
org.fusesource.scalate.NoValueSetException: The value for 'foo' was not set
at org.fusesource.scalate.RenderContext$$anonfun$attribute$1.apply(RenderContext.scala:159)
at org.fusesource.scalate.RenderContext$$anonfun$attribute$1.apply(RenderContext.scala:159)
at org.fusesource.scalate.RenderContext$class.attributeOrElse(RenderContext.scala:167)
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. It works for me when I try it. Do you have a test project somewhere? Also you can do: `val page = params.getAs[Int]("page").getOrElse(1)`

Comment: Sadly everyone says that it looks fine. I don't have the code any more because I switched to using Fink (A scalatra based CMS).

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the temp/generated files via the following command

```
sbt clean clean-files
```

Then start the Jetty server. It might help.